# How to get geocode change listener Yandex mapkit android?

Tags: android, geocode, yandex, yandex-maps

i used yandex mapkit try to get accurate latlng but it ploted accurately but not get listener failed i used the link https://github.com/yandexmobile/yandexmapkit-android/blob/master/yandexmapkit-sample/src/ru/mapkittest/geocode/OverlayGeoCode.java but listener not called how to get listener when each and every point move

Thanks,
Shabeer Mohamed

Answer (score 2):

If you want to geocode a point on a map after you tap on it, you need to do the following.

1. Extend Overlay class and implement GeoCodeListener

   ```
   public class GeoCodeOverlay extends Overlay implements GeoCodeListener {

       public GeoCodeOverlay(MapController mapController) {
           super(mapController);
       }

       @Override
       public boolean onFinishGeoCode(final GeoCode geoCode) {
           if (geoCode != null) {
               getMapController().getMapView().post(new Runnable() {
                   @Override
                   public void run() {
                       // show display name of the point
                       Toast.makeText(getMapController().getContext(),
                               geoCode.getDisplayName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                   }
               });
           }
           return true;
       }

       @Override
       public boolean onSingleTapUp(float x, float y) {
           getMapController().getDownloader()
                   .getGeoCode(this, getMapController().getGeoPoint(new ScreenPoint(x, y)));
           return true;
       }
   }
   ```
2. Example of usage

   ```
   public class GeoCoderActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_geo_coder);

           final MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);
           mapView.getMapController().getOverlayManager()
                   .getMyLocation().setEnabled(true);
           mapView.getMapController().getOverlayManager()
                   .addOverlay(new GeoCodeOverlay(mapView.getMapController()));

       }
   }
   ```
3. `activity_geo_coder.xml`. Don't forget to add your API key

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
       android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
       android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
       android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
       tools:context="com.mapkittest.GeoCoderActivity">

       <ru.yandex.yandexmapkit.MapView
           android:id="@+id/map"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="fill_parent"
           android:apiKey="PLACE_YOUR_API_HERE"
           />

   </RelativeLayout>
   ```